# Android studio Error:Configuration with name 'debug' not found

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

I have a problem. When I want do Gradle project sync in my project, he write:

```
 Error:Configuration with name 'debug' not found.
```

Only this one line, nothing more.
I don't know what he want from me.

Here is `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    }

}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

ext {
    apply from: 'cordova.gradle'
    cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 24
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the content of your `settings.gradle` file?

Comment: `include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"`

Comment: In your `settings.gradle` put `include ':CordovaLib'`, and your `build.gradle` should be under `CordovaLib/build.gradle` folder route. Or add the project name to `settings.gradle` file under `build.gradle` is placed.

Comment: the problem still here

Comment: You need to make sure that each `submodule` in your project has its own `build.gradle` file. The name 'default' happens because your outer `build.gradle` is trying to build a project that doesn't know how to build itself, thus it is given the name 'default.'

Comment: how ? i can't see any submodules

Comment: Could you run `gradle dependencies` command at your root project?

Comment: no, i can't do that

Comment: Have you found any solution? If yes, then please share it.

Answer (score 3):

I started to experence the error since I had updated cordova-android to 6.0.0.

I overcame it by using

```
android {
    publishNonDefault true
}
```

You can read about it here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication